# Why is this the condition for a map to be continuous?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am specifically looking at the following problem,

> Let $X=\{0,1\}$. For which topologies $\tau$ is $(X,\tau)$ contractible? Explain.

To show it is contractible, I consider the one point set $Y=\{0\}$. Now, I understand there are $4$ topologies I can define on $X$. Among which $\tau_2=\{\phi,X,\{0\}\}$ is causing me trouble with the following statement I found in the solution to this problem.

> Denote $X_2=(X,\tau_2)$. A function $\Phi:Y \to X_2$ is continuous if and only if $\Phi^{-1}(0) \subseteq Y$ is open.

Simply, why? Okay, here's the definition I am familiar with for continuous maps in the topological sense

> A mapping $f:(X,\tau) \to (Y,\tau ')$ is continuous if $G \in \tau ' \Rightarrow f^{-1}(G) \in \tau$. That is, the inverse image of every open set is open.

So, in our problem, $\{0\} \in \tau_2$ so it is an open set in $X_2$. Now, this means that indeed, $\Phi^{-1}$ must map an open set in $X_2$ to an open set in $Y$. But if I think about it, there is only one topological space constructible from $Y$, $Y=\{Y, \tau_y\}$ where $\tau_y=\{\phi, Y\}$. Namely, every subset of the topological space $Y$ is open.

**Question 1**
So, whatever $\Phi^{-1}$ is, whatever element of $X_2$ I input to $\Phi^{-1}$, shouldn't it *always* map it to an open element anyway? Then why bother even mentioning it? I mean, give me an example of a map $f:X_2 \to Y$ such that $f(x)$ is *not* open for $x \in X_2$.

**Question 2**
Why are we actually worried only about $\{0\}$? Why not worry whether $\Phi^{-1}(\{0,1\}) \subseteq Y$ is open or not too? What makes $0$ so special? Since $\{0,1\}$ (the entire set of $X$) is open in $X_2$, must we not worry whether $\Phi^{-1}(X)$ will be open in $Y$ or not considering the definition of "continuous maps"? Though, as I made my point in **Question1**,  don't see the point to worry at all in the first place since any choice I have to map in $Y$ is open anyway. But if someone convinces me that I need to, then this would be my next question.

**Question 3**
Actually, is it possible that $f(\phi)$ is mapped to something? Are "empty sets" also subject to some mapping? I can map an emtpy set to something...*not* empty? Like $f:\phi \to \{0\}$? I realized no one really ever explained to me clearly whether or not $\phi$ is considered to be a subject of a mapping. If it is, then as in **Question 2**...why don't we worry whether $\Phi^{-1}(\phi) \subseteq Y$ is open or not too?

Does anyone know clear answers to each of my $3$ questions? Best answer will be given to the person who has explained it clearly and easy-to-understand.

**Full solution to this part of the problem**

Denote $X_2=(X,\tau_2)$. A function $\Phi:Y \to X_2$ is continuous if and only if $\Phi^{-1}(0) \subseteq Y$ is open. the maps

$$f:X_2 \to \{0\};x \to 0 \text{ and } g: \{0\} \to X_2; 0 \to 0$$
are inverse homotopy equivalences with $fg=id_{\{0\}}$ and the map

\begin{equation}
 h: X_2 \times I \to X_2;(x,t) = \left\{\def\arraystretch{1.2}
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad}l@{}}
    0 & \text{if $0 \leq t <1$  }\\
    x & \text{if $t=1$  }\\
  \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

defining a homotopy on $gf$ and $id_{X_2}$.

Comment: Why are you looking at $Y$ and maps from $Y$ to $X$ in the first place? You’re interested in whether the identity map on $X$ is homotopic to one of the two constant maps on $X$.

Comment: Well, that's how it's written in the solutions...I can write down the entire solution for this bit though it's tedious if it will help.

Comment: Okay. I don’t immediately see the relevance of it, but you’re right that a one-point space has only one possible topology, and moreover that every function from it into any topological space is continuous.

Comment: For question 3 the answer is no. For all sets $A$ and $B$ and all functions $ \ f:A \to B$, the image $ \ f[ \varnothing] = \varnothing \ $ and the preimage $ \ f^{-1} [ \varnothing] = \varnothing$. We also have that $ \ A^{\varnothing} = \{ \varnothing \}$.

Comment: The $Y$ in the solution is not $\{0\}$: it’s $X_2\times I$. The point is that no matter what space $Y$ is, $\Phi^{-1}[\varnothing]$ and $\Phi^{-1}[X_2]$ will always be open, so in order to be sure that some particular $\Phi$ is continuous, we need only check that $\Phi^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott that makes it all the more mysterious, since the solution to the case $X_1 = \{X, \tau_1\}$ where $\tau=\{\phi, X\}$, it simply says "every function $\phi: Y \to X_1$ is continuous." If that's exactly the case here too, I really don't see why there's an "if and only if " statement. Bizarre.  And Gustavo, so it's more or less an implicit thing that the null set will be always mapped to the null set?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott really? how did you see that?

Comment: @John: That’s *not* the case here. Every function from any topological space to $X_1$ is continuous, but functions to $X_2$ are continuous if and only if the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under the function is open in the domain.

Comment: @John: How did I see what?

Comment: As in, how did you see that $Y$ in the solution is $X_2 \times I$? I can only think of it as $Y=\{0\}$ since aren't we trying to show that $X_2$ and the one point set $\{0\}$ are homotopy equivalent? And I don't see *why* "Every function from any topological space $X_1$ is continuous but functions to $X_2$ are...open in the domain". The latter statement is exactly what is said in the solutions but I'm just like 'but WHY?" Why $\{0\}$? Moreoever, if $Y= X_2 \times I$, which isn't a topological space (or...is it? $I$ is just an interval right..), how does one define "open" for $X_2 \times I$??

Comment: @John: $X_2\times I$ is just the Cartesian product of two topological spaces, so it has the product topology. If you’ve not dealt with product spaces before, you’re simply not yet ready for contractibility. However, I’m writing up an answer that is a expansion and reorganization of what I’ve already said in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar(in the sense that I know the definition or accessible to it) of the product topology...but if I remember correctly, I thought they re defined for topological spaces. $X_2$ is, with a specified topology, but $I$? what is the topology of $I$? it's an interval along the real line, but what topology is defined on it...will it be unique?

Comment: @John: $I$ has its Euclidean topology, the one inherited from the real line. (You can pretty safely bet that when $I$ is used in a topological setting without a topology being specified, the relative Euclidean topology is intended.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y$ be any space at all, and let $\Phi:Y\to X_2$ be a function. The open sets in $X_2$ are $\varnothing,X_2$, and $\{0\}$. $\Phi$ is continuous if and only if $\Phi^{-1}[\varnothing]$, $\Phi^{-1}[X_2]$, and $\Phi^{-1}[\{0\}]$ are open in $Y$. Now $\Phi^{-1}[\varnothing]=\varnothing$ and $\Phi^{-1}[X_2]=Y$, both of which are automatically open in $Y$, so $\Phi^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is the only one that we actually have to worry about: $\Phi$ is continuous if and only if $\Phi^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is open in $Y$.

> As an aside, if we had $\Phi:Y\to X_1$ instead, then $\Phi$ would automatically be continuous no matter *what* the space $Y$ was: the only open sets in $X_1$ are $\varnothing$ and $X_1$, whose inverse images under $\Phi$ are the open sets $\varnothing$ and $Y$ in $Y$.

Now let’s get back to the solution. In order for $X_2$ to be contractible, the identity map on $X_2$ must be homotopic to a constant map on $X_2$. The identity map is $\text{id}_{X_2}$ defined by $\text{id}_{X_2}(0)=0$ and $\text{id}_{X_2}(1)=1$. There are two possible constant maps on $X_2$, and we’re going to use the one that sends both points of $X_2$ to $0$: we’ll define $f:X_2\to X_2$ by $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0$. (By the way, my $f$ is the solution’s $gf$.)

Define

$$h:X_2\times I\to X_2:\langle x,t\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }0\le t<1\\
x,&\text{if }t=1\;.
\end{cases}$$

Note that $h(x,0)=0=f(x)$ for each $x\in X_2$, and $h(x,1)=x=\text{id}_{X_2}(x)$ for each $x\in X_2$, so by definition $h$ will be a homotopy between $\text{id}_{X_2}$ and the constant map $f$ **provided** that $h$ is continuous. This is where the first paragraph comes in, with $X_2\times I$ in the rôle of $Y$ and $h$ in the rôle of $\Phi$. That is, $h$ is a function from some space, in this case $X_2\times I$, to the space $X_2$, and as we saw in the first paragraph, it will be continuous provided that $h^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is open in $X_2\times I$.

Examining the definition of $h$, we see that $h(\langle x,t\rangle)=0$ if and only if $0\le t<1$, or $x=0$ and $t=1$. This means that the only point of $X_2\times I$ that is **not** sent to $0$ by $h$ is the point $\langle 1,1\rangle$. In other words,

$$\begin{align*}
h^{-1}[\{0\}]&=\big(X_2\times[0,1)\big)\cup\{\langle 0,1\rangle\}\\
&=(X_2\times I)\setminus\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}
\end{align*}$$

Now $\{1\}=X_2\setminus\{0\}$ is a closed set in $X_2$, since it’s the complement of an open set, and $\{1\}=I\setminus[0,1)$ is a closed set in $I$ for the same reason. Thus, $\{1\}\times\{1\}=\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}$ is a closed set in $X_2\times I$, and its complement $h^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is open in $X_2\times I$. It follows from the first paragraph that $h$ is continuous and hence that $X_2$ is contractible — specifically, contractible to the point $0$.

Comment: Thanks for writing it out, I'm giving it a read and going step by step, but when you say $f$ is a constant map, how is the definition "constant"? I thought constant maps $f:T \to S$ must map any element from $T$ to the *same* element in $S$. In this case, some constant map $f:X_2 \to X_2$ must map any element of $X_2$ to a single element, no? But $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ so it maps to $0$ *and* $1$. Or is the definition of constant maps different in topology...?

Comment: @John: Sorry: that was a typo. It should indeed have been $f(1)=0$, and I’ve fixed it now.